# Three JS Blender JSON EXPORTER smooth / flat shading

Tags: three.js, blender

Blender has the ability to set a material to Flat or Smooth.

In the Blender exporter for three.js, when I check "Export Normals" to JS model, I always export all materials as Smooth. The exported file is twice bigger.

Is there a way to export models with Flat Shaded and Smooth shaded faces without need to set it manually in three.js ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no flatshading/noshading/smoothshading equivalent in blender. However as few other features (blending, depthwrite, depthtest) it could be proposed in the 'threejs' part of the material pannel.

You could do it yourself by editing the following files in the addon :

- constants.py,
- __init__.py,
- exporter/material.py,
- exporter/api/material.py

(copy the way `blending types` work for example)

You would just pay attention that the blender `io-three` addon yet has a `shading` field for materials, used to define `phong` or `lambert` materials. You would just have to chose an other name.

Finally you would also have to edit threejs so the `JSONLoader` can parse the new property you add.

That said, it is a bit longer than setting your materials properties in your code, since you will always need to write `material=new THREE.Mesh****Material(properties)`...